# Recompile gcc with the built version

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am just wondering if it is a good idea [better optimization, less bugs] to recompile the `gcc` compiler with the own version.

I compiled `gcc 4.9.3` with the current system `gcc 4.3.4`. Once `gcc 4.9.3` has been compiled should I compile it again - and all other dependencies [`gmp`, `isl`, `mpc`, `mpfr`] - with the built version 4.9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc does this as part of its three-phase build: see the discussion of phase-2 and phase-3 compilers in *[Installing GCC: Building](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html)*

Comment: Thank you Thomas! But I could rebuild `gmp`, `ìsl`, `mpc` and `mpfr` which I had to compile in order to be able to build `gcc 4.9.3`. Should I then only link again `gcc` that the new compiled code is considered?

Comment: gcc is already linked; you *may* get some improvement by rebuilding things, but since it passes its self-test, the improvement may not be noticeable.